# Apache Commons toString utility that only includes fields that have value

Tags: java, apache-commons, tostring, utility-method

Is there a toString utility from Apache Commons that will only include in the resulting toString value those fields that are NOT null?

For example:

```
public class Person {
String name;
String height;
String age;
}
```

And create an instance where it has a name and age. Then calling the utility for example:

```
utility.toStringNonNull(person);
```

Will output:

[name=Mary, age=28]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to do this by extending Apache's ToStringStyle class:

```
public static class TestStyle extends ToStringStyle{
    TestStyle() {//constructor is copied from ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE
        super();
        this.setContentStart("[");
        this.setFieldSeparator(SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + "  ");
        this.setFieldSeparatorAtStart(true);
        this.setContentEnd(SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + "]");
    }

//override this to do checking of null, so only non-nulls are printed out in toString
@Override
public void append(StringBuffer buffer, String fieldName, Object value, Boolean fullDetail) {
    if (value != null) {
        super.append(buffer, fieldName, value, fullDetail);
    } 
}
```

Then use is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("Tester");
    ToStringStyle style = new TestStyle();

    System.out.println("toString = " + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(p, style));

}
```

This will result into:
Person@37403a09[
  name=Tester
]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
// dump content of person
DumpUtilities.dump(person);

// dump content of person and superclass
DumpUtilities.dump(person, 1);

// dump only filled content values of person and superclass
DumpUtilities.dump(person, 1, "onlyFilled");

// dump only filled content values with name starts with abc of person and superclass
DumpUtilities.dump(person, 1, "onlyFilled", "includeName=abc.*");

// dump only filled content values without name starts with abc of person and superclass
DumpUtilities.dump(person, 1, "onlyFilled", "excludeName=abc.*");
```

Here the DumpUtilities class

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public final class DumpUtilities {
    private DumpUtilities() {
    }

    /**
     * To dump a complete object.
     * 
     * @param object
     * @return print all fields of object.
     */
    public static String dump(Object object) {
        return dump(object, 1);
    }

    /**
     * To dump a complete object.
     * 
     * Example to print member variables of JFrame with name title
     * 
     * JFrame frame = new JFrame(""); frame.setTitle("hello");
     * logger.debug(dump(frame, 3, "onlyFilled", "newline", "indent=2"));
     * 
     * @param object
     * @param maxRecursionDeep
     * @param parameterArray
     *            "onlyFilled" print only filled values (default false),
     *            "newline" new line after every value (default false), "indent"
     *            count of indent spaces (default 0), "excludeType" to exclude
     *            types e.g. "excludeType=JTextArea", "excludeName" to exclude
     *            names e.g. "excludeName=abc.*", "includeType" to print only
     *            specified types e.g. "includeType=JTextArea", "includeName" to
     *            print only values with specified names e.g.
     *            "includeName=abc.*"
     * @return print all fields of object.
     */
    public static String dump(Object object, int maxRecursionDeep, String... parameterArray) {
        if (object == null) {
            return "null";
        }

        Class<? extends Object> objectClass = object.getClass();

        if (isInArray(objectClass, new Class<?>[] { Long.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class, Double.class, Short.class, Byte.class })
                        || objectClass.isPrimitive()) {
            return object.toString();
        }

        try {
            boolean onlyFilled = booleanParameter(parameterArray, "onlyFilled");
            boolean newline = booleanParameter(parameterArray, "newline");
            String indent = duplicate(" ", toInt(parameter(parameterArray, "indent")));
            String excludeType = parameter(parameterArray, "excludeType");
            String excludeName = parameter(parameterArray, "excludeName");
            String includeType = parameter(parameterArray, "includeType");
            String includeName = parameter(parameterArray, "includeName");

            if (objectClass == java.lang.String.class) {
                String s = object.toString();
                return onlyFilled && s.length() == 0 ? "" : "\"" + s + "\"";
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            if (objectClass.isArray()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object) && maxRecursionDeep > 0; i++) {
                    String value = dump(Array.get(object, i), maxRecursionDeep - 1, parameterArray);

                    if (onlyFilled && (value.length() == 0 || "null".equals(value))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    buffer.append((i == 0 ? "" : ",") + value.replace("\n", "\n" + indent) + (newline ? "\n" : ""));
                }

                if ((onlyFilled && buffer.length() > 0) || !onlyFilled) {
                    buffer.insert(0, "[");
                    buffer.append("]");
                }
            } else {
                while (objectClass != null) {
                    Field[] fieldArray = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length && maxRecursionDeep > 0; i++) {
                        String className;
                        String value;
                        Field field = fieldArray[i];
                        String name = field.getName();

                        if ((excludeName != null && name.matches(excludeName)) || (includeName != null && !name.matches(includeName))) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        try {
                            field.setAccessible(true);

                            Object fieldObject = field.get(object);
                            if (fieldObject != null && fieldObject.getClass().isArray()) {
                                String s = field.toString();
                                int index = s.indexOf("[");
                                className = s.substring(0, index >= 0 ? index : s.length());
                            } else {
                                className = field.getType().getName();
                            }

                            if ((excludeType != null && className.matches(excludeType)) || (includeType != null && !className.matches(includeType))) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (fieldObject != null && fieldObject.getClass().isArray()) {
                                className += "[" + Array.getLength(fieldObject) + "]";
                            }

                            value = dump(fieldObject, maxRecursionDeep - 1, parameterArray);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            value = e.getMessage();
                            className = field.getType().getName();
                        }

                        if ((onlyFilled && value.length() > 0 && !"null".equals(value)) || !onlyFilled) {
                            buffer.append(indent);

                            if (objectClass != object.getClass()) {
                                buffer.append("/* " + objectClass.getSimpleName() + " */ ");
                            }
                            buffer.append((className.equals("java.lang.String") ? "String" : className) + " " + name + "=");
                            buffer.append(value.replace("\n", "\n" + indent) + ";" + (newline ? "\n" : ""));
                        }
                    }

                    objectClass = objectClass.getSuperclass();
                }

                if ((onlyFilled && buffer.length() > 0) || !onlyFilled) {
                    buffer.insert(0, "{" + ((newline && buffer.length() > 0) ? "\n" : ""));
                    buffer.append("}");
                }
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return t + "\n" + stackTrace2String(t);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param regExArray
     *            array of regular expressions
     * @param string
     * @return true if any array member matches v
     */
    public static boolean matchesInArray(final String[] regExArray, final String string) {
        if (regExArray == null || string == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (final String regEx : regExArray) {
            if (string.matches(regEx)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param array
     * @param object
     * @return true if array contains v
     */
    public static <T> boolean contains(final T[] array, final T object) {
        if (array == null || object == null) {
            return false;
        }

        for (final T element : array) {
            if (element == object || object.equals(element)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static Method[] methodsWithAnnotation(Class c, Class annotation) {
        try {
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            List<Method> list = new ArrayList<Method>();

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(annotation)) {
                    list.add(methods[i]);
                }
            }

            methods = new Method[list.size()];
            return list.toArray(methods);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // ignore
        }

        return new Method[0];
    }

    public static Method[] methodsWithPrefix(Class c, String prefix) {
        try {
            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            List<Method> list = new ArrayList<Method>();

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].getName().startsWith(prefix)) {
                    list.add(methods[i]);
                }
            }

            methods = new Method[list.size()];
            return list.toArray(methods);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // ignore
        }

        return new Method[0];
    }

    public static String dumpBean(Object beanObject) {
        String name = null;

        try {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            stringBuffer.append("{\n");

            BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanObject.getClass());
            for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();

                Type[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
                if (parameterTypes.length > 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                name = method.getName();

                if ("getClass".equals(name)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Object value = method.invoke(beanObject);

                if (value != null) {
                    name = name.startsWith("get") ? (name.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + name.substring(4)) : name.startsWith("is") ? (name
                                    .substring(2, 3).toLowerCase() + name.substring(3)) : name;
                    stringBuffer.append("  /* " + method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName() + " */ " + method.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " "
                                    + name + "=" + value + "\n");
                }
            }

            stringBuffer.append("}\n");
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return "error by " + name;
        }
    }

    public static Object getField(Object object, String fieldName) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
                    IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = null;
        for (Class<?> c = object.getClass(); c != null && field == null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            try {
                field = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

        if (field == null) {
            throw new NoSuchFieldException();
        }

        boolean isAccessible = field.isAccessible();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object objectReturn = field.get(object);
        field.setAccessible(isAccessible);
        return objectReturn;
    }

    /**
     * @param object
     * @param memberName
     * @return child of object named memberName (also private member)
     */
    public static Object getMember(Object object, String memberName) {
        Object objectReturn = null;
        try {
            Field field = object.getClass().getDeclaredField(memberName);
            boolean isAccessible = field.isAccessible();
            field.setAccessible(true);

            objectReturn = field.get(object);
            field.setAccessible(isAccessible);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectReturn;
    }

    public static boolean isInArray(Object object, Object[] array) {
        return Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(object) != -1;
    }

    public static boolean isInArray(Class<?> c, Class<?>[] array) {
        return Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(c) != -1;
    }

    public static String stackTrace2String(Throwable t) {
        return t + "\n" + Arrays.toString(t.getStackTrace()).replace(", ", "\n  ").replace("[", "\n  ").replace("]", "\n");
    }

    /**
     * @param parameterList
     * @param name
     * @return hello for name b from parameterList "a=1,b=hello"
     */
    public static String parameter(String parameterList, String name) {
        return parameter(csv2arry(parameterList), name);
    }

    /**
     * @param parameterList
     * @param name
     * @return true for name a or b from parameterList "a,b=true"
     */
    public static boolean booleanParameter(String parameterList, String name) {
        return booleanParameter(csv2arry(parameterList), name);
    }

    /**
     * @param parameterArray
     * @param name
     * @return true for name a or b from parameterArray ["a","b=true"]
     */
    public static boolean booleanParameter(String[] parameterArray, String name) {
        String result = parameter(parameterArray, name);
        return result != null && (result.length() == 0 || Boolean.valueOf(result));
    }

    /**
     * @param parameterArray
     * @param name
     * @return null if name not found, "" for name a or "hello" for name b from
     *         parameterArray ["a","b=hello"]
     */
    public static String parameter(String[] parameterArray, String name) {
        if (parameterArray != null && name != null) {
            for (String parameter : parameterArray) {
                parameter = parameter.trim();
                if (parameter.contains("=") && parameter.startsWith(name)) {
                    String rest = parameter.substring(name.length()).trim();
                    String argument;
                    if (rest.startsWith("=")) {
                        argument = rest.substring(1).trim();
                    } else {
                        argument = "";
                    }
                    return argument;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String duplicate(String string, int count) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append(string);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    public static int toInt(String string) {
        try {
            return Integer.decode(string).intValue();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return 0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param parameterList
     * @return array ["a=1","b=hello"] from parameterList "a=1,b=hello"
     */
    public static String[] csv2arry(String parameterList) {
        if (parameterList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(parameterList, ",");

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
            list.add(token);
        }

        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
}
```